# Machine Learning in relation to personality and behaviors predictions

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, prediction, algorithm-request

I am tasked with making a machine learning model that predicts personality traits and behaviours of children based on simple and interactive quizzes.
Currently I am lost and have no idea where to start!

I am looking for guidance and where can start my research and the actual coding part and is NLP a good place to start from.

Comment: I would start with (child) psychology. If you don't know anything about personality traits and behaviours, and how they can be recognised, you will not be able to do this using machine learning.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by reviewing any available tools in NLP that can help you. I know two: Watson Personality Insights and Symanto thar provide API to develop this kind of solutions.

The first one was one available in the past [(Watson personality Insights](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights)) but unfortunately has been discontinued.

> The IBM Watson Personality Insights service enables applications to
> derive insights from social media, enterprise data, or other digital
> communications. T**he service uses linguistic analytics to infer
> individuals' intrinsic personality characteristics, including Big
> Five, Needs, and Values**, from digital communications such as email,
> text messages, tweets, and forum posts.
>
> The service can automatically infer, from potentially noisy social
> media, portraits of individuals that reflect their personality
> characteristics. The service can infer consumption preferences based
> on the results of its analysis and, for JSON content that is
> timestamped, can report temporal behavior.

Another comercial tool is [Symanto](https://www.symanto.com/):

> Symanto Insights Platform is an **AI-powered analysis tool** that gives
> you qualitative insights about your textual data. Just upload your
> data sets or crawl information from different sources such as online
> review sites or online surveys, and Symanto’s AI immediately analyses
> your data and provides you qualitative insights about the author.
> Symanto Insights Platform reveals the opinions of your customers and
> employees **by analysing text data**, giving you insights about current
> topics, general performances or the psychographic structure of your
> audience. Whether it’s psychographic marketing, customer service,
> product development or employee satisfaction, Symanto Insights
> Platform helps you answer a wide range of business questions.

I´m somehow working in this field in my Master thesis so if you need any further info just let me know.